# Using from Carbon package in where function in Laravel framwork

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want check which one of my orders submitted 30 minutes ago.
I am using from Carbon package for check this work.
So I used from this code but Laravel apears this error:
`DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (created_at) at position 0 (c): The timezone could not be found in the database`

```
$now = carbon::now();
    $orders= Order::where(Carbon::parse('created_at')->addMinutes(30) ,'>=' , h)->get();
    foreach($orders as $order){
        if (is_null($orders)){
            return 'false';
        }else{
            return 'true';
        }
    }
```

In fact I'm not sure about my code but if `where(Carbon::parse('created_at')` is incorrect, what is correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse` function expects a string date to parse it to a Carbon object, not the column name.

So you should change your check to this:

```
$orders = Order::where('created_at' ,'>=', now()->subMinutes(30))->get();
```

and I use the `now()` helper function in Laravel which is equal to `Carbon::now()`

Comment: @Adeveloper please consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful.